# How to remove a cumulative update from a SharePoint server

Tags: sharepoint

During the installation of the Cumulative Update June on my Dev machine, the SharePoint server crashed but didn't cancel the installation process. After running the configuration wizard I checked the SharePoint version which was still set to the version of the April update. So it seems that the SharePoint crash during the installation has also effects on the update.

I then tried to reinstall the update and to rerun the configuration wizard, but without success. The version number still showed the number of the April update.

So now I'm wondering if there is a way to remove/uninstall the cumulative update so I can try to reinstall it again or at least get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flo,

I think you're out of luck (and probably going to be on the phone with Microsoft PSS if you have such an arrangement).

Assuming a straightforward mechanism existed to restore the binaries present on each of your SharePoint servers to their pre-April CU state, you have another (bigger) challenge: the database schema and associated version that's tracked within the databases.

The process of rolling databases (configuration and content) forward is pretty straightforward and happens each time you update the farm, but I'm unaware of any way to rollback database changes associated with the new binaries.  If you were to try and attach farm members with older binaries to your databases, you'd likely be greeted with a schema mismatch error in the logs.

For what it's worth  :-(

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Given that there is no or no "easy" way to remove the update and given that it is only a dev machine, I will simply set up a new one. 

it is only my dev machine I messed up, I will simply create a new one.

Comment: +1: That's right... Microsoft's official stance on SharePoint, SQL Server, etc. updates is that there is no uninstall. I think SharePoint setup has a "Repair" option but doubt that would help here, and who knows what side effects it might cause.